# Low agreeableness on argumentations with people confident in rethoric

Tags: terminology

In many discussions people show [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias), [self serving bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-serving_bias) and mental rigidity.

Assume one of the actor is very confident with rhetoric and shows really low agreeableness and a [passive hostility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior) (the definition given by wikipedia fits very well) toward the other one. He can be frustrated or Narcissistic.

The other tries to express his perceptions of some reality but his argumentations are not perfect in the form in which they are formulated, so he is accused of the typical formal errors (i.e. "generalization", "you cannot be sure"). It's extremely easy to create a wall in this way (only philosophers or scientific papers are formally correct).

And the formal errors in an argumentation don't prove the speaker is wrong. But many people can think that winning an argumentation means being right.

This second guy (like the victim of many narcissists) could feel impotent, overwhelmed, or experience a kind of [Gaslighting](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting))

Is there a specific name for expressing this kind of argumentative hostility? Something like 'rubber wall'?

Comment: [Captiousness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captious)?